# Error: "Failed - No file" when downloading a file from app deployed on heroku

Tags: html, flask, heroku

I built a very simple app with flask that runs perfectly on local host. On the homepage the user can download some PDFs from a link, but when I try to do the same action on my app deployed on heroku it says "Failed - No file".

The app structure is the following:

```
app.py
resources
         |
         |-- regolamento2019-2020.pdf
         |-- regolamento2019-2020.pdf
templates
static
```

The HTML for the file download is this:

```
        <td>
            <a href="../resources/regolamento2019-2020.pdf" download="Regolamento_2019_2020.pdf">
                <img src="../static/red.png" alt="redKing" width=65 height=65>
            </a>
        </td>
```

I don't understand why it does not work on heroku. I also went in the console on the heroku dashboard and run bash too see the tree structure and to check if the files were there and I could see them. I also tried changing the path to

```
<a href="/app/resources/regolamento2019-2020.pdf" download="Regolamento_2019_2020.pdf">
```

since the current directory on heroku was /app.
Any idea on how I can fix this and make it work online and not only in local?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't include paths like `../static/something.jpg` in you templates.

Instead use Flask's `url_for` function do generate these links dynamically:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='red.png') }}" alt="redKing" width=65 height=65>
```

If you moved your `resources` dir into the `static` dir, you could then do:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('static', filename='resources/regolamento2019-2020.pdf') }}" download="Regolamento_2019_2020.pdf">Click</a>
```

Hovever to stick with the current location of your `resources` directory, you could write a custom route ([as per the example here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.send_from_directory)) like:

```
from flask import send_from_directory

@app.route('/resources/<path:filename>')
def download_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory('resources',
                               filename, as_attachment=True)
```

Then include that within your template as:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('download_file', filename='regolamento2019-2020.pdf') }}">Click</a>
```